# Should i use Local storage directly in Angular 2

Tags: angular, local-storage

Should i use local Storage directly in component , someone said it is bad practice to use window functions directly .

What would be good practice to use local storage in angular 2

Thank you in advance

Comment: Angular injectables can be easily stubbed or mocked. It's not that straightforward with globals. Angular Universal still doesn't support localStorage.

Comment: try to use angular cookies

Comment: @AppuAmruth you mean https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies ?

Comment: ya similar one https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to implement a `Service` that handles this.

Thid `Service` could check if the `localstorage` is present and use it.. if not it ignores those set/get functions or mock them in any other way..