# Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular

I am trying to set the items array and push to localStorage with the following code:

```
public onSubmit(thumbnail, quantity, product_name, product_price){

const data = {
   thumbnail,
   quantity,
   product_name,
   product_price
};

localStorage.setItem(this.items, JSON.stringify(data));
this.items.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(data)));
}
```

I get the following errors:

Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

for localStorage.setItem(this.items, JSON.stringify(data));

Argument of type '{ thumbnail: any; quantity: any; product_name: any; product_price: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

for this.items.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(data)));

In my HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items;">
<td>
<td><img src="../assets/images/gallery/{{item.thumbnail}}" /></td>
<td>{{item.quantity}} </td>
<td>{{item.product_name }}</td>
<td>{{item.product_price}} </td>
<td>{{item.quantity * item.product_price }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the ```setItem()``` key argument needs to be of type ```string```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: Outside of the function I have items = [];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use some string key to store something by this key in localstorage. I believe you wanted to store items in localstorage. it would look like this:

```
storageKey = 'MyDataStorageKey';
public onSubmit(thumbnail, quantity, product_name, product_price){

  const data = {
   thumbnail,
   quantity,
   product_name,
   product_price
  };
  this.items.push(data);


  localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(this.items));
}

ngOnInit() {
  const itemsStr = localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey);

  this.items = itemsStr ? JSON.parse(itemsStr) : []; 
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error message:
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
for localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, this.items);

Comment: I also get the error in the console: localStorage.get is not a function for const itemsStr = localStorage.get(this.storageKey);

Comment: pardon me. i fixed issues and updated the answer. now it should work

Comment: Thanks Andrei no errors now but I can still use the splice function to delete an item and if it were saved to localStorage, I would need to use localStorage.removeItem

Comment: if you modify an array (splice, push, concat, basically anything) then just evaluate "write to localstorage code" again. `localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(this.items));`

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. It is saving to localStorage now after all. Now that I deployed it, when I refresh the page, the products stay on the page.

Comment: so, is this post an answer to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you check out the [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) of `setItem`, you'll see the problem:

```
storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);

Parameters

keyName
    A DOMString containing the name of the key you want to create/update.
keyValue
    A DOMString containing the value you want to give the key you are creating/updating.
```

`keyName` is supposed to be a string. You use `this.items` as an argument, which, apparently, is an array.

Instead, you could try something like

```
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
this.items.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')));
```

**Update**: I should not post this without saying that you probably don't want to use `localStorage` directly in your Angular components. At least out-source it to a Service. For more details, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972227/should-i-use-local-storage-directly-in-angular-2).

Comment: Thanks, fjc. Your solution worked but it doesn't seem to be saving to localStorage. I can't check because I am in development mode so every time the page is refreshed, it gets recompiled. I can use the splice function to remove the product which tells me it's an array and not a storage item.

Comment: Another problem is that after I remove the product with splice and localStorage.clear();, the grand total still updates with the previous prices even though they should have been cleared.
I know I should be using localStorage.removeItem('') when I click on the delete button but for testing I'm clearing all the data.

Comment: I deployed my code to the Web and it's not using local storage. When I refresh the page, the items in the cart disappear.

Comment: @MaureenMoore We'd need a bit more code to understand, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when saving the data to local storage. localstorage setItem method expects two parameter where the first is the name of the property inside the localstorage and the second is the data to save.

The proper method to use is to

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', JSON.stringify(data));
```

More example can be found in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

THIS ISN'T WORKING SO IT'S NOT AN ANSWER BUT IT INCLUDES CODE SO IT COULDN'T GO IN THE COMMENT
Now that the product is being saved to localStorage, I need to delete the item. I am using

```
deleteItem(i){
localStorage.removeItem(i);
localStorage.setItem(i, JSON.stringify(this.items));
this.items.splice(i,1);
}
```

and I get the argument to the function from

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
<td>
<button type="button" (click)="deleteItem(i)">X</button></td>
</tr>
```